# Recuperación de nodos Firebase

Tags: firebase, ios, swift

Estoy intentando recuperar un nodo específico de Firebase únicamente con la variable tipo, como esta en la imagen, para agregarla a una tableView. En mí consulta ocupo **queryOrdered(byChild: "veterinarias")** pero no me muestra nada en la tableView [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí] Aquí esta mi código [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí] ¿Cómo puedo mostrar únicamente los datos que tengan el mismo valor que tenga tipo?

Answer (score 0):

1.- Ve a las reglas de tu base de datos y asegura que estas indexando(no se si es correcta esta palabra) de manera apropiada, ayudara a agilizar el proceso, ejemplo:

```
  "rules": {
    .... // me brincare demas reglas de autenticacion
    "veterinarias": {
      ".indexOn": ["tipo"]
    }
  }
}
```

2.- Tu peticion deberia ser mas como:

```
.ref.child('veterinarias').queryOrdered(byChild: 'tipo').queryEqualToValue('esteticas')
```

Aqui podras encontrar ejemplos de como realizar tu peticion:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/lists-of-data#filtering_data